# English sentence with Ago and Before

Tags: sentence-construction

1. I submitted the Inspection report to my boss one day ago before our office closed.
2. I submitted the Inspection report to my boss one day  before our office closed.

which one sentences above is correct. as i put ago in a sentence and in another without it so these double i want to clear.

Comment: Please capitalize the I pronoun in English.

Comment: Generally, we say "a" rather than "one", unless you are counting: one day ago, two days ago.

Answer (score 2):

*One day before our office closed* means that, on whatever date it closed, the report was submitted a day earlier.

*One day ago* means yesterday. If you add *before our office closed* it would mean 'yesterday, before the *time* that it closed'.

Answer (score 1):

*Ago* is always relative to the present. To speak relative to another time, you use the adverb *before* (or *earlier*): "I had submitted the report one day earlier".

In your examples, *before* is a preposition, and it is grammatically consistent with *ago*.

The first has some ambiguity: it might be further defining "one day ago [at a point during the day] before our office closed", or it might be providing further subsidiary information "one day ago [which was] before our office closed"

In the second sentence, "one day" is quantifying the *before*: "how long before the office closed? One day before it closed".

It could have an alternative reading (which was how I first read it), though this would usually have a comma: "one day, before the office closed". Here "one" is not a quantifier, but a determiner, meaning "a certain". So the meaning would be "on a certain day, an unspecified number of days before the office closed".

If it is modifying (quantifying it) "one day before our office closed".

The phrase "one day ago" is not very common, as in most contexts people would say "yesterday"

Answer (score 0):

An office usually closes every day say at 6pm, but also close say Dec. 23rd for Christmas.

The first sentence, i know exactly when you submitted the report.

The second sentence, you wouldn’t say that if your office closed every night. I’d assume there is a seasonal closure, and I don’t know when, and you delivered the report a day before that. Your colleagues and your boss would probably know when that was, except it could have been any time during that day.